# PHP running bash (.sh) script. dpkg --info works but not dpkg -i

Tags: php, bash, shell, terminal, dpkg

Sample PHP Script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
    $file = '/private/var/www/app/install.sh';
    if(is_file($file)){
        $output = shell_exec('bash /private/var/www/app/install.sh');
        fwrite(STDOUT, $output."\n");
    }
    exit(0);
```

install.sh Example

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Executing Install Script..."
dpkg --info /private/var/www/app/app.deb
dpkg -i /private/var/www/app/app.deb
echo "Script Finished"
exit 0
```

This will print out the resulting dpkg --info data, but it will not run dpkg -i. It doesnt print out any errors, or anything at all...

Also, this is being executed via a web web browser. When the script is run from the terminal, it works fine. But on the web, only the info command is returned.

Comment: Note that you are only seeing stdout. To see stderr you'll need to redirect `shell_exec('bash /private/var/www/app/install.sh 2>&1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably some security concerns with what you are trying to do here, and I'm not going to comment on those. However, I'd guess that `dpkg -i` needs to run as root, and your webserver (which executes the install.sh script) is not running as root. On the other hand, the `dpkg --info` command doesn't need root privileges to run, and so you will see its output when executed via the webserver's user. If you really need to run this script as root, you might want to look at a specific `/etc/sudoers` config. Perhaps start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

and take a look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821

Comment: Hola. I tried adding 

"%wheel ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dpkg
%root ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dpkg
wheel ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dpkg
root ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dpkg"

Not all at once, but those combos to run it, when I run the id command from the install.sh i get this. Also im using Lighttpd not apache.

'uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel)'

Comment: Hi, you need to match the /etc/sudoers entry to exactly the way that you will be executing the command. The way that you have written your question looks like you want to sudo execute install.sh (which, in turn, excutes dpkg...). You could put a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top of your install script. Then use /path/to/install.sh in the sudoers file. Something like: `WEBSRV_USER ALL=(root)NOPASSWD: /p/to/install.sh`. Then `shell_exec('sudo /p/to/install.sh')` Have a look at the second link in my answer above for more details. Also, do read up on the security concerns around using this approach

Comment: First off thanks so much! I followed your advice and added #!/usr/bin/env bash to my install script, and used visudo to correctly add a new rule for the script file. Then using shell_exec('sudo path/install.sh') the script is ran and things are installed! Stand up job sir :)

Comment: My pleasure, feel free to select my answer if you are happy with it :D

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --info` doesn't require root permission while `dpkg -i` does. Since you run your script on browser, this mean that your script run on php / apache's user. I believe, on most installation, that user doesn't have root permission.

To overcome this, you could create some sort of processor that will have the following step:

**create `queue` table**:

- queue_id
- timestamp
- deb_file
- is_processed

**browser script**:

- upon clicking on install, insert an entry to queue table.

**processor script (let's say `queue_processor.php`)**:

- upon run, check if there are entries on queue table whose is_processed = 0
- if there are any:

  - update is_processed = 1
  - process that file
  - after finished processing (installing deb file), set is_processed = 2

**The final step is, to set `queue_processor.php` on crontab and have it owner as root:**

```
*   *   *   *   *   root   /path/to/php/binary/php /path/to/your/queue_processor.php
```